# Is it possible to trigger a function for each element of an ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that will generate a list of div elements. What I'm trying to do is that for each of these elements, a function will trigger and get an image url specific to each div of the ng-repeat.

I've created a Plunker, if you search for an artist it will generate a list of releases, and if you click on each one of them, the cover art will appear, buuut it will appear the same image to each div!

So long story short, how to automatize the process (no ng-click required) and to make each image populate each corresponding div?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aYg1TbnRFwW1WhuPKYp?p=preview)

This is the function that should be triggered by each element of the ng-repeat by separate:

```
$scope.getImages = function (title, name) {
    $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json').
      success(function(data4) {
          $scope.images = data4;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new controller for each `release` object created by `ngRepeat`.

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="release in releases" ng-controller="ImageCtrl">
    <div class="release">{{release.title}}
        <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{image}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This controller then just gets the album information, and saves the desired image url to a variable on the the `release` object's scope:

```
app.controller("ImageCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + $scope.artist.name + '&album=' + $scope.release.title + '&format=json')
      .success(function (data4) {
        $scope.image = data4.album.image[2]['#text'];
      }
    );
});
```

I suspect that this wasn't working for you because the url was being saved to the main controller scope, instead of the repeated release object's scope.

Here is a working subset of your plunker, that demonstrates retreiving the images this way: http://plnkr.co/SMUVAngg444UICH6tULE

Comment: I've learned more of Angular with this answer combined with a couple of days of fighting with this issue, than with 3 tutorials...

Comment: Just another quick question, can a $timeout delay be implemented into this same function, or I need another one? The API from Last.fm goes bananas if I launch too many requests at once...

Comment: I would implement paging so that you only request a handful of releases at a time.

Comment: The thing is that Lastfm will only allow 5 requests per originating IP address per second, averaged over a 5 minute period. I'll have pagination but only because of the Discogs limitations (will only list 100 releases at a time). The problem is that even if I have 50 results displayed at once, lastfm would get 50 requests at once, and even if inside the parameters of the limitation, sometimes it'd cancel the request... I thought that with a 200-300ms delay per request, it would take it more easily...

Comment: Personally I would rather have 5 show up immediately than have 50 trickle in.  But, Yes, with some  reorganization of your code you could use timeout to slow down the requests.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I'll implement pagination. The only issue with pagination is that the filters will only work with each page separately. That's a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

When the data comes back from the search, can you automatically start the getImages call for each one?  Then when that data comes in, put the urls in the results objects and use an ng-repeat and/or ng-src to show them.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could do this before the ng-repeat. But that could be a lot of data calls.

So instead, consider using [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) within your `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datum" ng-init="getImages(data.title, data.name)"></div>
```

Comment: It works, but it is still populating the same image in all divs! :S

Comment: are different titles & names being passed to `getImages()`?

Comment: Yes! Different titles, name is the same.